# Python client code gets Address already in use error

Tags: python, sockets, http, client-server, bind

I have a simple Python HTTP server which also connects other HTTP servers to fetch some data. While, connecting to other servers, my server acts as an http client, but the socket created for incoming connection requests still keeps listening from port 8080 (I have a different socket for the client).

The list of other servers that I need to connect and fetch data is stored in a JSON file and I have code like this

```
with open(myjsonfile, 'r') as json_file:
    entries = json.load(json_file)
    for entry in entries.keys():
        address = entries[entry]['address'] 
        port = int(entries[entry]['port'])
        client_port = config.server_port + 50000
        host = gethostname()

        # request the TXT file
        sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        # sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((host, client_port))
        sock.connect((address, port))
        reqmsg = "GET /" + config.txt_name + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
        sock.sendall(reqmsg.encode())
        response = ''
        response = sock.recv(2048).decode()
        pos = response.find("\r\n\r\n")
        txt_data = response[pos+4:]
        # processing the received data here
        sock.close()

        # request the IMG file
        sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        # sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((host, client_port))
        sock.connect((address, port))
        reqmsg = "GET /" + config.img_name + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
        sock.sendall(reqmsg.encode())
        response = b''
        while True:
            recvdata = sock.recv(2048)
            if (len(recvdata) < 1): 
                break
            response = response + recvdata
        pos = response.find(b"\r\n\r\n")
        img_data = response[pos+4:]
        # working with the image here
        sock.close()
```

I have to use a set port number for my client because this is how the server identifies me. However, I sometimes get an "Address already in use" error for the second `socket.bind()` call (the one for the image). Without the `bind()` calls, my code works fine.
I tried setting socket options (commented out in the code above) and using pycurl with the `LOCALPORT` property set to `client_port` value above, but still getting the same error.

What could be the reason behind the error message? I think I open and close the sockets so the operating system should free the port for further use (I think)?

Thanks

PS : This is a small project, not a production system, hence do not bother with "why use port numbers to identify clients"

Answer (score 0):

There is a TIME_WAIT after the session is shutdown to make sure that there are still no live packets in the network.When you re-create the same tuple and one of those packets shows up, it would be treated as a valid packet for your connection this will cause an error state.Usually 2xpacket max age, before the packet is discarded

Before you create a connection with the same tuple, all the packets from the previous session must be dead.

Try using;

```
...
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.listen([backlog])
sock.bind((host, client_port))
...
```

[socket.listen([backlog])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen)

Comment: I am not trying to `listen()` from this socket. However, when adding a `listen()` call before `bind()`, it fails with `sock.bind((host, client_port)) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: You have already bound to the port at first run, that's why the second run fails and throws the error.. refracture the code to get bind out of the for loop...create the socket first outside the for loop